# Navlink - React Router Dom not working in React.Js

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I am using redux with react. I have a map method on my navigation menu and I want to navigate to /products using Navlink - react router v5.2. But when I click on shop link button it goes to products page but again I click on my logo and come back on homepage and again I click on shop link button then it doesn't navigate. What is the issue in my code? Below is the code and screenshot attached for your reference.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./header.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setHeaderData } from "../../redux/actions/header-actions/HeaderActions";
import { setBgColor } from "../../redux/actions/header-actions/HeaderActions";
import Loading from "../other/loading/Loading";
import PageNotFound from "../other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const headerData = useSelector((state) => state.header.headerData);
  const bgColor = useSelector((state) => state.header.bgColor);
  const { bgColour, borderColor, iconColor } = bgColor;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // get header data
    getHeaderData();

    // send object for changing bg colour
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      changeNavBg({
        bgColour: "bg-black",
        borderColor: "border-white",
        iconColor: "text-white",
      });
    });

    return () => {
      // remove changeNavBg event on scroll
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeNavBg);
    };
  }, []);

  // change nav bg colour on scroll
  const changeNavBg = (bgColor) => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
      dispatch(setBgColor(bgColor));
    } else {
      dispatch(
        setBgColor({
          bgColour: "bg-transparent",
          borderColor: "",
          iconColor: "",
        })
      );
    }
  };

  // get header data
  const getHeaderData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/navLinks");
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        dispatch(setHeaderData(data));
      } else {
        setIsLoading(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // if loading is true return Loading
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading loadingHeader={"header"} />;
  }

  // console.log(bgColor);

  return (
    <>
      {headerData ? (
        <div className="dvHeader">
          <nav
            className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg ${bgColour} navbar-light fixed-top`}
          >
            <div className="container">
              <div>
                <button
                  className="navbar-toggler"
                  type="button"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#slideDownMenu"
                  aria-controls="slideDownMenu"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                  <span className="">
                    <i className={`fa fa-bars ${iconColor}`}></i>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="order-lg-0">
                <NavLink to="/">
                  <img
                    width="50"
                    src={headerData.logo.url}
                    className="img-fluid"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </NavLink>
              </div>
              <div className="order-lg-2 d-lg-none">
                <span
                  className="d-flex"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#mobileCartModal"
                >
                  <span className="d-inline-block mr-1">
                    <i className={`fa fa-shopping-cart ${iconColor}`}></i>
                  </span>
                  <span className={`d-inline-block ${iconColor}`}>0</span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div
                className="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-1"
                id="slideDownMenu"
              >
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto px-3">
                  {headerData.parentLinks &&
                    headerData.parentLinks.map((parentLink) => {
                      const { id, link, subLinks } = parentLink;
                      return (
                        <li key={id} className="nav-item dropdown">
                          <NavLink
                            className={
                              id !== 2 ? "nav-link" : "nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                            }
                            to={id === 1 ? "/products" : ""}
                            id="navbarDropdown"
                            role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                          >
                            {link}
                          </NavLink>
                          <div
                            className={id === 2 ? "dropdown-menu" : "d-none"}
                            aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"
                          >
                            {subLinks &&
                              subLinks.map((subLink) => {
                                const { id, link } = subLink;
                                return (
                                  <a
                                    key={id}
                                    className="dropdown-item"
                                    href="#"
                                  >
                                    {link}
                                  </a>
                                );
                              })}
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      );
                    })}
                </ul>
                <form className="dvSearch my-2 my-lg-0 px-3">
                  <input
                    className={`form-control border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 mr-sm-2 ${
                      window.innerWidth > 991 ? borderColor : ""
                    }`}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search"
                  />
                  <button className="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                    <i className={`fa fa-search ${iconColor}`}></i>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <PageNotFound />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

APP.JS

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./containers/home-page/index";
import Header from "./containers/header/Header";
import Footer from "./containers/footer/Footer";
import ProductListing from "./containers/products/product-list/ProductList";
import ProductDetail from "./containers/products/product-detail/ProductDetail";
import PageNotFound from "./containers/other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";
import Account from "./containers/account/index";
import Checkout from "./containers/checkout/Index";
import LoginModal from "./containers/auth/modal/login-modal/LoginModal";
import SignupModal from "./containers/auth/modal/signup-modal/SignupModal";
import MobileCartModal from "./containers/products/mobile-cart-modal/MobileCartModal";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Homepage} />
          <Route path="/products" exact component={ProductListing} />
          <Route path="/productdetail" exact component={ProductDetail} />
          <Route path="/checkout" exact component={Checkout} />
          <Route path="/account" exact component={Account} />
          <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
        <LoginModal />
        <SignupModal />
        <MobileCartModal />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

DB.JSON

```
"navLinks": {
    "logo": {
      "url": "LOGO"
    },
    "parentLinks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "link": "Shop"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "link": "Learn",
        "subLinks": [
          { "id": 1, "link": "Process" },
          { "id": 2, "link": "About Us" },
          { "id": 3, "link": "Blog" },
          { "id": 4, "link": "News" },
          { "id": 5, "link": "Beyond The Bottle" }
        ]
      },
      { "id": 3, "link": "Sign Up" },
      { "id": 4, "link": "Login" }
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this navigation issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, check now I have edited question and added a complete header.js and app.js code.

Comment: Seems like the issue is isolated to the `NavLinks`. Can you add this `headerData` object to your question? And if possible, create a running sandbox that we can debug against?

Comment: added headerData object please check.

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navlink-react-router-dom-not-working-in-react-js-qg2js) and I'm unable to reproduce the navigation issue between `"/"` and `"/products"` that you describe. Perhaps there is more to your code? Feel free to fork the sandbox and add more of your code until it breaks and reproduces the issue.

Comment: thanks, Now I added all the code to sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/navlink-react-router-dom-not-working-in-react-js-forked-foceb?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you mock all the data and other asynchronous calls? It looks like the CSB is looking for a server you're running locally. The CSB doesn't get past the loading screens. I commented all that out in `Header.js` and stubbed the `headerData` and can reproduce the issue. If I comment out the bootstrap imports in `index.js` the links work. I'd ditch bootstrap, it's a bit dated, but that's just my opinion. It's not immediately clear to me why the link works the first time and not any subsequent time.

Comment: It's a Bootstrap dropdown menu and when you click the bootstrap's function run and show us the dropdown. I had just hide all the dropdowns but not the function which runs on click. I think that is the issue. First then I have to figure out how to disable that function onclick for other navlinks except learn link. Anyways thanks Drew you helped me so much. Please let me know if you get something. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey Drew I found the answer and thanks to you. I did this ---> data-toggle={id !== 1 ? "dropdown" : ""}. I removed data-toggle attribute which toggles the dropdown when id is 1

Comment: Sounds great, glad to help! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I removed the bootstrap attribute "data-toggle" when id is 1. Check the code below now it's working. The Bootstrap Toggle Attribute was causing an issue.

```
<NavLink
   className={
    id !== 2 ? "nav-link" : "nav-link dropdown-toggle"
    }
   to={id === 1 ? "/products" : ""}
   id="navbarDropdown"
   role="button"
   // removed bootstrap attribute
   data-toggle={id !== 1 ? "dropdown" : ""}
   aria-haspopup="true"
   aria-expanded="false"
 >
   {link}
</NavLink>
```